# Favicon não mostrando

Tags: html, css, favicon

Boa tarde,

Gostaria da ajuda dos universitários, criei um site e coloquei uma favicon na mesma pasta que as páginas que a chamam, mas o favicon não está sendo mostrado:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
```

Link de acesso: https://www.glonatec.com/

Comment: Aqui tá mostrando.

Comment: DVD em todos os pcs testados não apareceu, estranho demais isso

Comment: Aqui tá aparecendo.

Comment: Troque "image/png" por "image/x-icon"

Comment: Aqui também mostra... Talvez seja simplesmente cache... Tente atualizar a página apertando CTRL+F5

Comment: Tentei atualizar com o CTRL+F5 mas deu na mesma, não sei se é meu computador, mas no de vocês está mostrando, mas no pessoal que tenho que entregar o projeto, não funciona =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nem todos os navegadores são capazes de reconhecer os favicons. Tente utilizar o Google Chrome ou Mozilla Firefox e certifique-se se estão atualizados.

No caso do site que você informou, aqui eu pude visualizar sem problemas utilizando a última versão do Mozilla Firefox. Segue print:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Eu sei que já explicaram a razão, mas só pra reforçar, cada navegador pode operar de uma maneira diferente, por isso existem **TAGS** corretas para cada um isso variando de computadores pra smartphones.

Eu pesquisei e vi que é necessário criar dois arquivos ambos com 32x32 px sendo um no formato ICO (Convertido e não salvo por editores de imagem) e outro PNG:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Para evitar CACHE aconselho mudar o nome dos arquivos por que seu navegador pode não entender de primeira.
Existem também as TAGs para outros vários navegadores, principalmente de Smartphones que vou colocar aqui se estes não resolverem o seu problema.

Use esse conversor online se quiser gerar todos os formatos necessários de modo automatizado:

**https://realfavicongenerator.net/**

(Ele também gera todas as tags necessárias para o cabeçalho do seu HTML)